# How to prevent users from creating folders in SourceSafe

Tags: directory, addition, visual-sourcesafe, restrict, rights

We still use Visual SourceSafe 6.0. I would like to block my teams from creating projects (folders) on SourceSafe and only have Check-in, Check-out, and **Add files** rights. Yes, I would like them to be able to **Add files**,  but not create or rename or delete folders.

How might I go about getting this in place?

Answer (score 0):

I learnt the VSS security setting before at [this blog](http://www.kevingao.net/sourcesafe/how-to-manage-security-in-sourcesafe-vss.html). The problem is the rights for "Add Project" and "Add file" are not separate. They are both controlled by "Add/Rename/Delete".

I do have two suggestions below:

1. Disable the "Add/Rename/Delete" right for root directory($/), but assign the right to all folders under $/. This way, users cannot create folders/files anymore under $/.
2. Migrate to a better version control system, such as [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/).